# iptable-restore sets INPUT allow all

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-12.04

This is my /etc/iptables/rules.v4

```
*filter

-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

# Accepts all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allows all outbound traffic
# You could modify this to only allow certain traffic
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

# Allows HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere (the normal ports for websites)
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allow ftp
-A INPUT  -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 21 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# Allow Active FTP Connections
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# Allow Passive FTP Connections
-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024:  -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allows SSH connections
# THE -dport NUMBER IS THE SAME ONE YOU SET UP IN THE SSHD_CONFIG FILE
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Now you should read up on iptables rules and consider whether ssh access
# for everyone is really desired. Most likely you will only allow access from certain IPs.

# Allow ping
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

# log iptables denied calls (access via 'dmesg' command)
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7

# Reject all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy:
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT

COMMIT
```

No rocket science at all, copy-paste from http://wiki.debian.org/iptables. The problem is when I finally iptables-restore it, "ACCEPT all anywhere/anywhere" rule is inserted in the beginning of each chain:

```
root@host:/etc/iptables# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             127.0.0.0/8          reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp state NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp-data state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spts:1024:65535 dpts:1024:65535 state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables denied: "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ftp state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ftp-data state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spts:1024:65535 dpts:1024:65535 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

I know, iptables-restore are flushing all previous tables prior to loading saved rules.
Have no idea where those "ACCEPT all". 
Help, please.

Comment: Have you tried intentionally flushing the rules and then reloading?

Comment: Use the `-v` option when inspecting your configuration.

Comment: Yes, I tried to flush previous results. The solution is in answer below

Answer (score 1):

As Kathrine mentions, you need to make sure you are flushing all your chains before hand.

```
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -F FORWARD
```

I also opt to flush the policies:

```
iptables --policy INPUT DROP
iptables --policy FORWARD DROP
iptables --policy OUTPUT DROP
```

Comment: iptables -P is the shorthand (just in case you've been doing --policy).

Answer (score 1):

There is no flushing problem.
This happens because you added a rule to allow all trafic in your loopback interface. 
If you use "iptables -L -v" you will see that the "allow all" rule applies only to the local loopback interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is missing this:

```
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
```

It would appear before the listed rules had you set the policy to default with these commands:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

So if you set the default policy and then run `iptables-save`, you should see the lines above. Save that to your file, and restoring with `iptables-restore` will work.

Comment: That only sets the policy, it wouldn't add a rule.

Comment: When you set the policy and save it with `iptables-save`, it will be part of the resulting file. Notice how I said "before the listed rules".

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have a rule that allows traffic from anywhere to anywhere:

`-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

Of course it only allows packets for established sessions, but `iptables -L` doesn't show that. Try `iptables -L -v` for fuller output.

Comment: Thank you, Dennis. iptables -L -v is more informative.
 209K   83M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED